# Make Android app only work on a specific WiFi network

Tags: android, wifi

I was wondering if there is a way I can build an android app and make it so that it only works with a specific WiFi SSID?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You'll need to get information about the wifi networks, check which one is connected and only proceed if it's the one you need.  Post your existing code and we can try to help you resolve issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). It has everything you need to get started.